# Windows 11 and Ubuntu, Different Drives

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I want to install ubuntu on a different drive. Do I have to unplug Windows 11 drive in order for Ubuntu not to install stuff on it? Or maybe ubuntu does not install anything on different drives when they are connected, but only to the drive which is choosen? I just want to have two isolated systems. One for work, one for private stuff and I don't want for my work drive to install or touch anything on a private one and vice versa.

Comment: It'll use the preexisting ESP (EFI System Partition) for the bootloader, that's all. When installing or using it won't write to the Windows partitions unless you tell it to do that. And this isn't something new, it always has been since dual-boot was invented.

Comment: Be aware of launchpad bug 1396379, installer ignores your bootloader location information and uses first ESP it finds.  Is your second disk removable?  Do you ever want to boot without the second disk?  The suggestion to remove the first disk during install to the second disk is to avoid having grub wired to both disk, needing both to boot successfully.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Ubuntu on another drive, at installation select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and it will ask you, what is the drive you want to install it.

So you just have to select the drive you want to install Ubuntu, and Ubuntu will not install anything on the Windows 11 one.

Yes, Ubuntu will only install on the chosen one, but if you feel safer, you can unplug the Windows one.